# delta dirac δ(t) integral evaluation confusion.

Tags: definite-integrals, dirac-delta

I do understand that we define the integral of  δ(t) equal to 1, i know that we purposely choose n and 1/n as shown in the picture below, but i need help please to improve my understanding over it. 
I know that if i use high school geometry Area= base x height = n x 1/n = 1, but that is not using the standard calculus numerical method.

I am scouring over other mathstack's threads and trying to understand δ(t) as much as possible. I try to numerically evaluate the integral and i cannot get it equal to 1. That is the essence of my question and my problem.

[image]
$$\begin{align}
Area &=\int_0^n \delta(x)dx\\
&= \int_0^n \frac1n\, dt \\
&=-[\frac{1}{n^2}]\Bigl\vert_0^n \\
&=-[\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{0^2}]\\
&= problem:\,cannot\, divide\, by\, zero
\end{align}
$$
Is it possible to calculate numerically the inegral using the above standard method? How? What is the correct solution? I can't make it equal to 1. I ended up getting something that is impossible to compute.

Comment: $n$ is a constant and not an integration variable or function thereof.  So, $\int_0^n \frac1n \,dx=\frac1n \int_0^n (1)\,dx$.

Comment: thanks a lot :)

Comment: Dirac Delta is not a function but a distribution. So maybe you should read something about that to be able to understand perfectly well what Dirac Delta actually is.

Comment: @Dog_69 if only you could provide me with some 'keywords' to look for in docs, forums and preferably online videos. I have a moderate understanding of calculus, i can't understand hard core math which are written to be understood by mathematicians.

Comment: I think in your case the best place to start is Wikipedia's articles: [Dirca Delta function ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) and [Dirac meausre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure), as well as the definitions of [meausre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) and [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). Moreover, you may find interesting the note on https://www.phas.ubc.ca/~berciu/TEACHING/PHYS312/LECTURES/FILES/dirac.pdf. Finally, I'll say you that you can think Dirac Delta as the limit of many function sequences.

Comment: @dog_69 i have seen the definition of the limit: lim( δn(t) ) = δ(t),as n goes to infinity, and i need to understand the meaning of this limit definition better... i barely get it.

Comment: From which reference have you seen it?

Comment: @Dog_69 I took it from a non English textbook (i have the paperback version of it ). I made a mistake: the book is talking about a generic function fn(t), where  lim( fn(t) ) = f(t),as n goes to infinity.  I made a mistake above and wrote  lim( δn(t) ) = δ(t). Of cource, i still i don't really comprehend that definition of the limit. It seems that there is great theoretical depth i need to cover.,(i remember the basics of limits theory):-(

Comment: The limit you're asking is the limit of a sequence: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence in particular in metric spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $\int_0^n \frac 1n dt$ you are integrating with respect to $t$, not $n$, so you just get 
$$\int_0^n \frac 1n dt=\left.\frac tn \right|_0^n=\frac nn-\frac 0n=1$$

There are a couple small problems with your model of the delta "function".  The first is that it should be even, so your rectangle should be centered on zero.  The second is that you should at least think of it with a $\lim_{n \to 0}$ out front.  In fact, any shape will do equally well as long as it is strongly peaked around zero, has area $1$, converges to $0$ for all $x \neq 0$ in the limit.

Comment: " it is strongly peaked around zero " .Ιf it was δ(t-to) in that case it should be centered around to?

Comment: The delta function should be centered around zero.  If you use $t-t_0$ as the argument the peak will be shifted to be around $t_0$, but that doesn't change the function unless you write something like $f(t)=\delta(t-t_0)$

Comment: If we're talking about distributions as functionals on spaces of continuous functions, then there is absolutely no reason why the individual functions of a 'model' of the dirac delta *must* be even. Such a choice may have technical advantages in some arguments, but that's it. There is a lot of freedom in how you can choose the model; what matters most is that it has the correct limit as a functional. Heck, you can even model the dirac delta with a sequence of functions each of which is identically zero on a neighborhood of zero!

Comment: @Hurkyl:  I had always seen that as part of the definition.  I think it comes because in practice we often want to integrate it multiplied by odd functions and it is convenient to have that be guaranteed to be zero.  In many cases it wouldn't matter.

Comment: (also, pointwise convergence to zero is not required either)